Can't make Code Navigation to ( C/C++extension)
I have a vscode project, my code is managed with CMake, and builded by ARM toolchain. I can't make the code navigation to work properly. When I ctrl+click on something (or press F12), either nothing happens or it send me to the first reference of the file. I can't navigate to header file when I ctrl+click on an include file. Here is my c_cpp_properties.json :
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "__CC_ARM",
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "forcedInclude": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/boards/config_project.h"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/10 2020-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm",
            "configurationProvider": "nordic-semiconductor.nrf-connect"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I launch vscode at the root of my folder, which looks like this : 
I tried to give the path to ARMCC toolchain, but the extension doesn't seems to recognize it. I tried MSVC compiler also.
Thank you for your help !
